# Como puedo refrescar los datos de Vuejs al momento de cerrar una Ventana?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente problema, no puedo refrescar mi lista de clientes al momento de agregar un dato y cerrar la ventana normal, al momento de darle click se abre una ventana de cliente, se cierra, pero el dato que se agrega, no aparece en el listado.

```
Mi HTML:
    <div class="row col-md-12" id="create_factura">
                   <div class="">
                      <a href="#" onClick="window.open('{{ action('ClienteController@create')}}','popup', 'width=400px,height=450px')" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
Mi VUE:
new Vue({
  el: '#create_factura',
  created: function(){
    this.getClientes();
  },
  data: {
    clientes: [],
methods:
  {
    getClientes(){
      axios.get(urlClientes).then(response => {
        this.clientes = response.data
      });
    },
   FiltroCliente(){
      return this.clientes.filter((cliente) => {
        return cliente.nombre.match(this.busca2);
      });
    },
}
```

Quisiera una solución aunque me tocara que agregar un boton de refrescar para que aparezca.

Comment: Deberías colocar un [ejemplo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), sobretodo el template completo donde supuestamente iteras a tus `clientes`. supongo que `FiltroCliente()` debería funcionar como una computed property y `this.busca2` no se de que contexto proviene porque de `data` no lo hace.

Answer (score 0):

Si la lista de clientes que tienes se está generando con un v-for entonces lo único que tienes que hacer es añadir a tu propiedad this.clientes  el nuevo cliente. Claro que con la misma estructura de los otros clientes que ya están en el Array this.clientes, por ejemplo:

```
this.clientes.push(nuevoCliente);
```

Comment: Fijate que la añadición de un nuevo cliente está hecha por la función create/store del controlador de laravel, como muestro en el código html, de hecho intenté crear un boton donde llame a la función getClientes otra vez, pero no los refresca.